# php PDO read to table statement

Tags: php, sql, pdo

here is the code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ";

foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo "<tr>"."\n";
    echo '<td>'. $row[CODE].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row[FIRME_CODE].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row[NOM_LEGAL].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row[NO_CIVIQUE].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row[NOM_RUE].'</td>';
    .... and so on ...
    echo "</tr>"."\n\n";
}
```

the question, how it's possible to output all the value found from the query into a table WITHOUT having to tell each array table value individually...

it does not make sens... so there must be a way to do it, fast...

--

after changing it to this.. it output the word : Array in each table cell

```
<td> Array </td>... not good !
```

So the question is... what is the error in this code ?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ";
$rows = $db->query($sql);

echo '<tr>';
foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
    echo '<td>', $key, '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: You're going to want to specify the columns in your select statement instead of using `*` in order to maintain the column order (especially if you have a `<thead>` row with column headings)

Comment: you need to use error reporting level E_ALL instead of E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE

Comment: `$row` (`foreach ($row as ...`) is not the same as `$rows` (`$rows = $db->...`). Change your foreach to `$rows` -> `foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {...`

Comment: after changin it.. it output in each <td> Array !

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL); if the FIRST thing in my php file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo '<tr>';
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    echo '<td>', htmlspecialchars($value), '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
```

Note that I've added `htmlspecialchars()` which will escape your arbitrary data for use in HTML, generating valid HTML and preventing against potential XSS attacks (depending on where that data comes from).

Comment: @plainjane 4 up, 1 down

Comment: @menardmam What error?  I didn't test it, but I don't see a problem here.

Comment: It's NOT ERROR anymore, it's the word ARRAY instead of the value INSIDE of it !

Comment: @menardmam Can you do a `var_dump($value)` in the loop?

Comment: @menardmam Brad's answer requires you to create a `foreach` loop **inside** your original loop. Note the placement of `echo '<tr>'` in relation to your original question

Answer (score -3):

put the query result in an array

and then foreach the array

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ";

$rows = $db->query($sql);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  echo '<td>'.implode('</td><td>',$row).'</td>';
}
```

Comment: its not different from what OP is doing

Comment: @YourCommonSense How's that? This looks *functionally identical* to the OP's code

Comment: @YourCommonSense I looked. The only difference is this answer introduces a local variable `$rows` for the result of `PDO::query` whereas the OP uses it directly in the `foreach`. The left operand used in the `foreach` will be the same thing (a `PDOStatement` instance)

Comment: My bad. Looks like I thought of something else while looking at this.